# SELECT entre dos fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2005

Estoy intentando hacer un `SELECT` que me traiga todos los registros que estén entre dos fechas. Sin embargo, quiero ignorar el tiempo (horas, minutos, segundos, etc...). Por ejemplo, tengo un registro que tiene `2016-11-14 11:47:56.207`, pero yo envío por parámetro a mi `stored procedure` solo `14-11-2016`. Si lo envío así, no recibo resultado.

```
WHERE GRP.GRP_Fecha BETWEEN @desde AND @hasta
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, si no especificas hora, se toma automáticamente la media noche (00:00:00.000), lo cual puede hacer que se escapen algunos resultados que sí esperas que estén. No sé si es ese el problema que estás encontrando.

Comment: Claro, al yo enviar por ejemplo 14-11-2016 el resultado que puse en mi pregunta, no aparece

Comment: Pero eso va a depender de los valores de `@desde` y `@hasta`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro entiendo lo que dices, pero si el usuario envia desde y hasta iguales? tampoco se va a reflejar. Tampoco si pone como fecha fin algun registro que si tenga esa fecha pero más horas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu caso, te sugiero de evitar cualquier solución que envuelva hacer un `convert` u otro tipo de conversión con el campo `GRP_Fecha`. Al hacer eso, no le permites a SQL Server de poder usar un índice si lo hay para el campo `GRP_Fecha` y esto puede afectar tu rendimiento de forma muy obvia.

Y, por supuesto, `between` no es ideal en este caso específico por las razones ya mencionadas en tu pregunta.

Te sugiero la siguiente condición para el mejor rendimiento (buen uso de los índices) y para evitar problemas con las horas:

```
where GRP.GRP_Fecha >= @desde
  and GRP.GRP_Fecha < dateadd(day, 1, @hasta) -- @hasta + 1 día
```

En el caso donde:

- `@desde` = `2016-11-01`
- `@hasta` = `2016-11-14`

... la condición equivale a:

```
where GRP.GRP_Fecha >= '2016-11-01'
  and GRP.GRP_Fecha < '2016-11-15' -- esta es la parte clave
```

Al pedir las fechas anteriores a `2016-11-15`, esto incluye todas las fechas de `2016-11-14` sin importar la hora.

Comment: Lo aplique y funciono a la perfeccion!... como consulta dateadd que hace principalmente con esos parametros? Me refiero a porque day?

Comment: En este caso, le estoy pidiendo de agregar un día a la fecha `@hasta`. De modo que si `@hasta = 2016-11-14`, la condición se convierte en `and GRP.GRP_Fecha < '2016-11-15'`.

Comment: Para incluir las horas... perfecto no se me habia ocurido! Gracias @sstan

Answer (score 2):

Yo resolví el problema con la función `convert`. Para tu caso sería

```
WHERE convert(date, GRP.GRP_Fecha) BETWEEN @desde AND @hasta
```

Comment: estoy trabajando con sql-server-2005 y no existe date :/

Answer (score 0):

Este te funcionara aunque tenga formato de Año/mes/dia : Hora:Min:Seg

```
 select * from table where Date >= '2016-10-01' and Date <= '2016-11-01'
```

Comment: Si un registro tiene la fecha `2016-11-01 11:47:56.207`, similar al ejemplo de la pregunta, esta consulta no la va a devolver.

Answer (score 0):

Hola tengo el mismo problema pero mi fecha de inicio es 12/07/2023 y el hasta es 15/08/2023 los datos lo ingreso con un cuadro combinado, cuando lo hago con fechas del mismo mes no hay problema pero cuando lo hago con fechas de distinto mes como el ejemplo solo me sale fechas del "desde'

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hola Ronnie, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, 

si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, antes 

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.